# How to store analytics data with firebase as a Backend?

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, analytics

I'm a bit lost here and I hope that you can help me out :)

Use case: You're building a blogging platform where the authors of the blogs can see how many views and scrolls their readers have made and where their readers come from.

I'm wondering how would you store this metadata with firebase as a backend?

Writing on every new page view seems like a really costly and ineffective approach.

I know that you can integrate bigQuery - but as far as I understood bigquery has a time delay on its operations and I'm not sure how I would approach even trying to show bigqueries data on the client-side

What would be the way to approach this?

Thanks!